# Full-width div with perspective

Tags: css

I just recently started toying with perspective and 3D transformations, and understand why my div is not showing up at 100% width (even with it set in the CSS). However, for what I am trying to experiment with, I would like the div to stretch across the full width of the browser responsively. I would just use pseudo-classes to give it the perspective effect if it weren't for the text inside needing to have the same perspective.

http://codepen.io/hiremarklittle/pen/OMBQBJ?editors=1100

```
  html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #777;
    }

  article {
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 85% -100%;
            perspective-origin: 85% -100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
            perspective: 300px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  div {
    background: #1a1e1a;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 100px auto 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 80px 30px;
            transform-origin: 80px 30px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg) translateX(37px);
            transform: rotateY(20deg) translateX(37px);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 3px solid transparent;
  }
```

If I set the width to like 156% I think it was, it stretched all the way across, but not responsively. I'd imagine there would have to be some sort of calc() algorithm or JS/JQuery involved, but I'd have no idea where to even start.

Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: Y dont you just use `perspective-origin: 100% -100%;`? Also u may add a `margin-left: 80px` to balance it horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your bit of code , a box-shadow would visually do the job,

```
box-shadow:  50vw 0 #1a1e1a
```

but what about a img in bg and having content to go all the way to the edge ?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPdpXG?editors=0100

Comment: The box shadow worked perfectly. I am trying to avoid images to save on load time, however little it may be.